# Swift - UITabBarContorller Initial View - when to force launch login screen?

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, uitabbarcontroller

I have programatically set up a custom UITabBarControler with three tabs, each of which is a UIViewController embedded a UINavigationController.

I am not using storyboards. I set the custom tab controller as the root in AppDelegate

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController =  CustomTabBarController()
```

The app runs fine and I get the three tabs and can move between them.

sample of how tabs are populated (in viewDidLoad of the customer tab bar controller)

```
let ordersVC = OrdersViewController()  // where Orders is a UIViewController
ordersVC.title = "Orders"
ordersVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let ordersVCNavi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ordersVC)
ordersVCNavi.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
...
viewControllers = [homeVCNavi, inventoryVCNavi, ordersVCNavi]
```

Now I need to first to see if the user is logged in (using Firebase).  I can easily check for already logged in (Firebase cached) or not logged in.

I do this logged in check in AppDelegate

My problem is when I need to force a login (jump to login view controller). I can not find a place that works.
- tried placing the call in the custom UITabBarController didLoad and the code is ignored
- tried placing the call in the didLoad and the willAppear in the initial tab controller also ignored

I can place a button on the initial tab and that button will indeed launch the login controller. So I can get to the login controller from a button press.

upon pressing a button I can execute this code and the login controller will show

```
let vc = LoginViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

But if I know I need to force login and I try to do that same code snip above in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` in the initial tab controller, or in the custom UITabBarController then the push is ignored.  Nothing happens.

What is best practice for forcing login screen when initial view is tabbarcontroller?

Where should one put the navigation to the login controller to force login when not already logged in.  Want to go to login so that user can not use the app if not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 if loggedIn {
      window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()
 }
 else {
      window?.rootViewController =  LoginViewController()
 }
```

after your login is successful

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController  = CustomTabBarController()
```

Comment: works great.  Then when user specifically requests to log out ... I do UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController  = LoginViewController()